# Unable to install keyval.sty

Tags: installing, texlive, key-value, repositories

I have a minimal TeX Live installation in `~/texlive/2014`.

I was trying to install `keyval.sty` using `tlmgr`.

So, I tried,

```
tlmgr install keyval
```

But it gives an error:

```
tlmgr: package repository http://ctan.imsc.res.in/systems/texlive/tlnet
```

package keyval not present in package repository.

CTAN [has the keyval package listed](http://ctan.org/pkg/keyval).

Am I doing something wrong? How do I get it right?

Comment: There is no `keyval` TeX Live package; `keyval.sty` is already part of the standard LaTeX distribution, so you shouldn't need to install it.

Comment: @egreg I installed using minimal scheme (to quicken the installation). I then installed xetex, geometry and latex packages. While compiling a fairly basic file, it gave me an error ! LaTeX Error: File `keyval.sty' not found.
So, I went to install keyval

Comment: @ChristianHupfer xkeyval does not help either. It still gives the same error.

Comment: Also, after the minimal scheme installation, all have done is install theose three packages, run fmtutil --all a few times and tried compiling that simple .tex file

Comment: @deshmukh: On a hint by Joseph Wright, on should not recommend `xkeyval` for some reasons, but I believe, this is not the issue at the moment.

Comment: This is the place, where it's located on my computer: `/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty`. I would dare say, it's one of the packages always being installed

Comment: `keyval` is part of the core LaTeX distribution: if you have LaTeX at all then you should have it. If not, check that both `required` and `tools` are installed: without them, you are in big trouble with LaTeX.

Comment: @JosephWright required and tools are packages? How do I install these using tlmgr?

Comment: @deshmukh `keyval.sty` is in the `graphics` package, thinking about it. So `tlmgr install graphics` should do it. However, I'd strong suggest installing the 'core' LaTeX bundle: `tlmgr install collection-latex`.

Comment: @JosephWright perfect. Installed collection-latex and a few others like collection-xetex. If you post an answer, I will accept it.

There is another problem with font not being identified. But I will post a separate question for the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using LaTeX (realistically) requires a minimum set of packages in addition to the kernel itself. The team distribute them as `required` and `tools`, but there is further sub-division. For example, `keyval` is part of `graphics` which is part of `required`. The easiest way to get the minimum set is to install the collection defined to cover exactly this case

```
tlmgr install collection-latex
```

More generally, there is not a one-to-one correspondence between the release name of a package (as on say CTAN) and the TeX Live name needed to install it. Particularly for larger bundles a bit of work may be needed to find the right name.